# Tomcat High Cpu Usage

Tags: java, tomcat

We have 2 tomcat instances running on the same server of which one is causing regular high cpu load. I have run a profiler on the server but it has only told me that java.lang.Thread.run() is hogging the cpu nothing more conclusive. The cpu spikes are from 0% to 45/55% every 4 seconds.

Is it possible that it is not the application itself but a misconfiguration of the apache part? How would i go about finding the issue?

Comment: Have you profiled memory? Perhaps you're trashing GC?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe blocked threads ? Look here for how to make thread dumps and check for blocked threads.

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2281